# use flask-wtf form validations without an actual form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to use flask-wtf form validators on some vaiables. All the examples for form validations uses actual form to do the validation. I want to use the validators on few variables without a form. Below are the snippets. I tried this way but it's of no use. I am getting False on form.validate() and I am getting [] lists for errors. Please guide me with the right process.

```
#this is my form_validations.py
#########################################################################################################
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, Length


class SignUpForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=50)])
    email = StringField('email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    mobile = StringField('mobile', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=10, max=15)])

#########################################################################################################

#this is the function where I want to use the form validations.
def userSignUp():
    username = request.form['username']
    email = request.form['email']
    mobile = request.form['mobile']
    form = {
        "username" : str(username),
        "email": str(email),
        "mobile": str(mobile)
    }
    formData = MultiDict(mapping=form)
    print(formData)
    form = SignUpForm(formData)
    if form.validate():
        output = {"result": "success"}
    else:
        output = {"result": "failed"}
    # print(form.validate(),form.username.errors,form.email.errors,form.mobile.errors)
    return jsonify(output)
```

Comment: Have you set up [CSRF with Flask-WTForms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html)? The field errors will be empty if it's an issue with the CSRF token.

Comment: @KarlSutt yes I think it's csrf_token issue. I can now see csrf_token missing in form.errors. Do you know how to fix this? I am running flask on localhost and using the api's from a static html file file:///C:/Users/hellohackers/Documents/GitHub/myapps/routes_use/signup.html. I have setup the CSRF with flask still csrf issue.

Comment: If you have set CSRF up like described in the [docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html), perhaps you are not sending the token along when you submit the form? Your HTML form should include a call to `{{ form.csrf_token }}`.

Comment: @KarlSutt iam not using form.csrf_token cause at the end I will just use flask apis for a mobile app. do i have to send a csrf_token to the client first then for other requests client needs to send me the csrf_token for api calls?

Comment: A-ha, got it. In this case, I would drop Flask-WTF and use WTForms directly. You can just `from wtforms import Form` instead of `from flask_wtf import FlaskForm` and swap `FlaskForm` for `Form` in your form class definition. Everything else should work pretty much as-is. Be sure to check out [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/166798) about REST API security as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example.

The route:

```
@app.route("/signup", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    form = SignUpForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        app.logger.info(f'Form validated - data: {form.data}')
        # redirect somewhere upon success...
        # return redirect('/somewhere')

    return render_template("signup.html", form=form)
```

The class code:

```
class SignUpForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=1, max=50)])
    email = StringField('email', validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Email()])
    mobile = StringField('mobile', validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=10, max=15)])
```

Slight modification on my end (the validators), because I import like this:

```
from wtforms import (
    Form, validators, widgets, FieldList,
    BooleanField, TextField, IntegerField, SelectField, SelectMultipleField,
    TextAreaField, StringField, SubmitField
 )
```

---

The template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Sign up{% endblock %}

{% block subtitle %}Sign up{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Sign up page</h1>

{% if form.is_submitted() and form.errors|count > 0 %}
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{ form.errors|count }} error(s):
    <ul>
    {% for field_name, field_errors in form.errors|dictsort if field_errors %}
        {% for error in field_errors %}
            <li>{{ form[field_name].label }}: {{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
{% endif %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form class="row g-3" method="post" action="{{ url_for('signup') }}" class="form-inline">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="mb-3 col-md-4">
            <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
            {{ form.username(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 col-md-4">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
            {{ form.email(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 col-md-4">
            <label for="mobile" class="form-label">Mobile</label>
            {{ form.mobile(class="form-control") }}
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" id="save" name="save" class="btn btn-success" value="save">Save</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I am using Bootstrap, so you can see I am letting Flask_wtf automatically generate the form fields but apply certain classes. However, I have added a submit button manually but you include it in your form as an optional field. Also you can add all the form fields yourself, then make sure they keep their original names. NB: I added the hidden CRSF field too (populated automatically).

The key is to use **validate_on_submit** to force validation of the form and populate the list of errors. As you can see, the template can iterate on the list of errors and display them as list items.

---

Here is what the form looks like:
[image: Demo of signup form]